Contrapositive to upper bound on number of maximal cliques in $N_{t+1}$-free graphs
This is essentially a follow-up to this question. I realized I was asking the wrong question for what I wanted to know.
Background
For a positive integer $t$, let $N_t$ denote the cocktail party graph of order $t$. For a graph $G$, let $\kappa(G)$ denote the number of maximal cliques of $G$.
The following theorem is given in An Upper Bound on the Number of Cliques in a Graph:
Theorem. Let $t$ be a natural number, and let $G$ be an $N_{t+1}$-free graph on $n \geq 4 t$ vertices. Then
$$
\kappa(G) \leq (n/t)^{2t}.
$$
It follows from this that if the largest $N_t$ induced subgraph in $G$ is upper bounded by a constant, then $\kappa(G)$ is polynomial in $n$.
Question
What is the contrapositive statement to this theorem in terms of asymptotics?
I am getting a bit confused trying inverting the various quantifiers, and I'm not sure how to negate asymptotic bounds in general. What I want to say is a statement along the lines of: "If the number of maximal cliques of $G$ is super-polynomial in $n$, then $G$ contains a $N_t$ induced subgraph of size $\Omega(n)$." How can this be made precise?
